# Error defining variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am writing simple housekeeping script. this script contains following line of codes.This is a sample code i have extracted from the actual code since it is a big file.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 ARCHIVE_PATH=/product/file

 FunctionA(){
    ARCHIVE_USER=user1  # archive storage user name (default)
    ARCHIVE_GROUP=group1    # archive storage user group (default)

    functionB
 }

 functionB() {
    _name_Project="PROJECT1"
    _path_Componet1=/product/company/Componet1/Logs/
    _path_Component2=/product/company/Componet2/Logs/


     ##Component1##
     archive "$(_name_Project)" "$(_path_Componet1)" "filename1" "file.log" 
 }

 archive(){
     _name= $1
     _path=$2
     _filename=$3
     _ignore_filename=$4
     _today=`date + '%Y-%m-%d'`
     _archive=${ARCHIVE_PATH}/${_name}_$(hostname)_$(_today).tar
     if [ -d $_path];then
        echo "it is a directory"
     fi
 }

 FunctionA
```

When i run the above script , i get the following error

```
@localhost.localdomain[] $ sh testScript.sh
testScript.sh: line 69: _name_Component1: command not found
testScript.sh: line 69: _path_Component2: command not found
date: extra operand `%Y-%m-%d'
Try `date --help' for more information.
testScript.sh: line 86: _today: command not found
it is a directory
```

Could someone explain me what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable expansions are incorrect -- you're using `$()` which is for executing a subshell substitution. You want `${}`, i.e.:

```
 archive "${_name_Project}" "${_path_Componet1}" "filename1" "file.log"
```

As for the `date` error, no space after the `+`.

Comment: after applying your changes it gives me following error message

testScript.sh: line 87: [: missing `]'

Comment: @KItis add a space before the `]`. It worked before most likely because `$path_` expanded to nothing.

Comment: When after adding this change too it return the following error  testScript.sh: line 80: PROJECT1: command not found ------------------Here line 80 is _name=$1

Comment: this error is also resolved after removing space between _name= $1 to _name=$1. thanks for you for all the help

Answer (score 3):

I see the line: _today=`date + '%Y-%m-%d'`

One error I spotted was resolved by removing the space between the + and the ' like so:

_today=`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`

I don't see where the _name_Component1 and _name_Component2 variables are declared so can't help there :)

Answer (score 1):

a few things... you are using $(variable) when it should be ${variable}
on the date command, make sure there is no space between the + and the format
and you have name= $1, you don't want that space there